# Logger field injection and unit tests

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, mockito

I have the following piece of code:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    private Service service;

    @Inject
    public MyBean(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

I used constructor injection in order to have clear list of dependencies required by MyBean, but I have also decided to use field injection for logger (since most the the classes would require this extra parameter in constructor, which just feels not right).

I want to use Mockito for testing and I have the following options to use:

1. @InjectMocks

   - I have read in multiple places to avoid it
   - I can't configure mock before my class is initialized
2. Inject logger with Whitebox

   - use of reflection
3. Use SpringRunner

   - is it really necessary to create Spring context just to instantiate one class for unit test?

Is there any cleaner way to accomplish that?

Comment: what exactly you want to do with logger? what did you tried and failed?

Comment: I want to unit test MyBean, which uses the logger. I need some way to ensure that logger is initialized in the test. I am trying to find the best way to do so.